# SQL Server POWER function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bigint

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 when I enter the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(POWER(2.0, 63.0) AS BIGINT);
```

Which yields the result:

```
9223372036854775800
```

However, using the Windows desktop calculator and raising 2 to the 63 yields:

```
9223372036854775807
```

Can someone please explain the difference -- or is there some internal conversion that SQL Server is doing? ... or am I missing something else?

Comment: But it is cast to a BIGINT -- Guys -- open up your windows desktop calculator and enter 2 raised to the 63 -- it gives 9223372036854775807 -- which matches the upper limit of in the SQL docs of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 -- so HOW do you use SQL POWER function to get the same answer?????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The range of `BIGINT`in MS Sql Server is:

```
-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)
```

And your calculator is giving you the wrong number, because 2^63 can't have an odd number for its right-most digit.

The `POWER` function in SQL Server (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx), returns the same type as its first argument.

The correct way to write this query is:

```
DECLARE @foo REAL = 2.0
SELECT CAST(POWER( @foo, 63.0 ) AS BIGINT)
```

By which, you will get `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.` error message. 
And about the reason that's
http://www.extremeoptimization.com/resources/Articles/FPDotNetConceptsAndFormats.aspx

And regarding the question of why `POWER` function is returning a wrong number? As @simonatrcl mentioned in his answer, there is arithmetic problems with floating-point numbers which sometimes result in invalid result. You can read about floating-point numbers and the problems with them here:

http://www.extremeoptimization.com/resources/Articles/FPDotNetConceptsAndFormats.aspx

You can also check the boundaries for integer types in MS Sql Server here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Comment: First of all, 2^63 can't be `9223372036854775807` and if you check `9223372036854775807 = 2^63 - 1`. However, here he is trying to calculate `2^63` which is bigger that what a BIGINT can hold.

Comment: Guys -- open up your windows desktop calculator and enter 2 raised to the 63 -- it gives 9223372036854775807 -- which matches the upper limit of in the SQL docs of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 -- so HOW do you use SQL POWER function to get the same answer?????

Comment: You can't. Floating point arithmetic is not guaranteed accurate.

Comment: @user1377587 You can't trust the result of windows calculator for such large numbers. 2 to power of any number will have an even number for it's right-most digit and never an odd number! That's a simple calculation rule. If you try the same calculation here http://www.online-calculator.com/scientific-calculator/ you will see `0` as the ressult

Comment: If you guys try `DECLARE @foo BIGINT = 2.0 SELECT POWER( @foo, 63 )` you will get `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.` error in SQL Server.

Comment: As @simonatrcl said, there is rounding problem in floating-point arithmetics. Same scenario is true with float data type in C# which has rounding problems. For getting the correct result, we should write it like this: `DECLARE @foo REAL = 2.0
SELECT CAST(POWER( @foo, 63.0 ) AS BIGINT)` and this will give us the error message.

Comment: The same is true for `decimal`. It returns invalid result because of the same reason as `float` type

Comment: manman -- makes sense -- windows calculator is incorrect and overflow is occurring as you describe for the POWER function; order is restored to the universe!

Comment: Good answer @manman. More detail than mine, and better explained. Nice one -

Comment: @user1377587 happy that I could help you to figure out the problem

Comment: @simonatrcl Thank you also for pointing out the Float-point problem.

Answer (score 3):

Power will be returning a FLOAT. Floating point numbers are not accurate beyond certain limits, and will drop a bit of accuracy (if you've ever has a negative 0 problem you'll know what I mean!).

That's what you're getting here...

Comment: I didn't actually check that the answer it was giving was wrong, but did check the number of significant digits which is > 14. My experience is that DOUBLE starts loosing precision at 14 or more.

Comment: Up to about +/- 328, yes! (Not sure it's actually 328, but it's close!)

Comment: However, given negatives, the limit is actually 2^63-1 - not so easy!

Comment: The preceeding two comments were in response to a since deleted comment which was along the lines of 'But it should be able to cope with int powers of 2 easily'. The comment has sine been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the calculator goes and tested on XP, Win7 and Win8.1:
2^63 = 9223372036854775808 (obviously)

As far as MSSQL goes:
The upper limit of a BIGINT is defined as 2^63-1, meaning 1 less than 2^63
Now if you would like MSSQL to calculate that for you one would be tempted to write something like:

```
SELECT POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 63) - 1
```

The result would be a bigint because you've cast the first argument of the power to a bigint. MSSQL will first calculate the power and then subtract 1. However, since the result of the power would exceed the range of a bigint, this statement will fail: `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint.`

So let us invoke some math to solve this. I assume everyone agrees with

```
2^4 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2 * (2^3) = 2^3 + 2^3
```

and thus

```
2^4-1 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1 = 2 * (2^3) - 1 = 2^3 + 2^3 - 1
```

That's what we're going to make use of...

```
SELECT POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 62) + (POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 62) - 1)
```

This results in `9223372036854775807` which is indeed the upper limit of a bigint.

Note that the () around the subtraction is really needed. Otherwise the addition of the result of the two powers would be done first, again resulting in an overflow.